# Weird Behavior of Scala Future and Thread.sleep

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, sleep, future

I'm currently writing codes to extend the Future companion object. One function I want to implement is `Any`

```
//returns the future that computes the first value computed from the list. If the first one fails, fail.
def any[T](fs: List[Future[T]]): Future[T] = {
  val p = Promise[T]()

  fs foreach { f => { 
    f onComplete { 
      case Success(v) => p trySuccess v 
      case Failure(e) => p tryFailure e
    } 
  } }

  p.future
}
```

I tried to test my code with

```
  test("A list of Futures return only the first computed value") {
    val nums = (0 until 10).toList
    val futures = 
      nums map { n => Future { Thread.sleep(n*1000); n } }

    val v = Await.result(Future.any(futures), Duration.Inf)

    assert(v === 0)
  }
```

But the returned value is 1, not 0. When I switched sleeping time to `n*1000` to `(n+1)*1000`, it works fine(returns 0).

Is there any special effect when called sleep on 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` is a blocking operation in your `Future` but you are not signaling to the `ExecutionContext` that you are doing so, so the behavior will vary depending on what ExecutionContext you use and how many processors your machine has. Your code works as expected with [`ExecutionContext.global`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) if you add `blocking`:

```
nums map { n => Future { blocking { Thread.sleep(n*1000); n } } }
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add `blocking` block. I missed that these thread are run in an execution context. Your solution works totally fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function name is `any` so I think you implement `any` right way. 
But if you want the first one you just get the 1st element from the List argument `fs` and complete with a promise.

Comment: I think i misused the word "first" in the comments. I wanted to - and the requirements describes - return the value that is calculated first in the time domain. I'm pretty certain that this implementation satisfies the requirements.